# openURL: with a NSURL containing a formatted NSString isn't working

Tags: iphone, nsurl, openurl, stringwithformat

To open Google Maps with directions, i'm using a formatted NSString inside a NSURL. But it doesn't work with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:nsurl];

code:

```
NSString * directionsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%@&saddr=%@", @"Hartenseweg 16, Renkum", @"1 Infinte Loop, Cupertino"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:directionsURL]];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLWithString: returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981390/urlwithstring-returns-nil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[NSString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` to ensure you get a properly encoded string for a url.