# Data argument not used by format string but it works fine

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsstring

I used this code from the Stack Overflow question: [URLWithString: returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981390/urlwithstring-returns-nil):

```
//localisationName is a arbitrary string here
NSString* webName = [localisationName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSString* stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@,Montréal,Communauté-Urbaine-de-Montréal,Québec,Canadae&output=csv&oe=utf8&sensor=false", webName];
NSString* webStringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
```

When I copied it into my code, there wasn't any issue but when I modified it to use my url, I got this issue:

> Data argument not used by format string.

But it works fine.  In my project:

.h:

```
NSString *localisationName;
```

.m:

```
NSString* webName = [localisationName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hősök_tere", webName];
NSString* webStringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];

[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

How can I solve this? Anything missing from my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` in the original string is used as a placeholder where the value of `webName` is inserted.  In your code, you have no such placeholder, so you are telling it to put `webName` into your string, but you aren't saying where.

If you don't want to insert `webName` into the string, then half your code is redundant.  All you need is:

```
NSString* stringURL = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hősök_tere";
NSString* webStringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];

[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+stringWithFormat:` method will [return a string created by using a given format string as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a). And in the first code block, `%@` will be replaced by value of `webName`.

In your modified version, the ***format*** parameter, which is `@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hősök_tere"`, does not contain any *[format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)*, so

> > `NSString* stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hősök_tere", webName];`

just runs like this <sub>(with the warning `Data argument not used by format string.`)</sub>:

> > `NSString* stringURL = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hősök_tere";`