# UITableViewCell images not loading ios

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiimage, nsurl

I am trying to download images asynchronously and display them in UITableViewCell imageView. The problem is that my NSURL is nil for some reason..

```
        NSString *urlString = feed[@"imageURL"];
        NSLog(@"urlString %@", urlString);

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];            
        NSLog(@"url image %@", url);
```

This will print something like

```
urlString http://www.....image.jpg
url image (null)
```

Can someone please tell me why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981390/urlwithstring-returns-nil) help?

Comment: oh, i thought you were having issues going from NSURL to UIImage... I guess I misinterpreted your question :(

Answer (score 0):

What your doing is getting the contents within a url with `NSURL`. Once you have the contents of the  url, you are basically saying to the compiler, load these SOMETHING contents from this url. But that SOMETHING whether it's an image or json object or whatever, needs to be loaded into an `NSData` object then load the `NSData` object into a `UIImage` object. Now you can just say `cell.imageView.image = theUIimage` for your exact problem but heres a simple example that just loads such `UIImage` into a `UIImageView` like so:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/37.gif"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
imageView.image = img;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Please no downvote :)

Comment: Fine for no down votes, but the way you are downloading image from url it will block main thread because you are using synchronous connection.