# Getting an image fails to create NSURL

Tags: ios, nsurl

Im trying to get an image from a url link.

```
        NSURL *thmbnailUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:800/fishtune/movie/%@.png",[[DBHelper sharedInstance] currentHostIP],[arr objectAtIndex:0]]];
        NSLog(@"thmbnail:%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:800/fishtune/movie/%@.png",[[DBHelper sharedInstance] currentHostIP],[arr objectAtIndex:0]]);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:thmbnailUrl];
        NSLog(@"movimgdata:%@",data);
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
        NSLog(@"movimg:%@",data);
        NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

when i log thmbnail i get this "ipofserverinnetwork/fishtune/movie/Our Logo 480p back.png" 
Note:i didn't put the original ip.

I get null when i log data and of course img will also be null. I really dont know why I'm getting null. because when I tried entering the url in a browser it displays the image. I used the same code in another part of my app and it works but when i used it in this it fails. Is it because of the spaces between "Our_Logo_480p"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLWithString: returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981390/urlwithstring-returns-nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need to use

```
NSString* escapedUrl = [yourstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it's because of spaces, use

```
 NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:800/fishtune/movie/%@.png",[[DBHelper sharedInstance] currentHostIP],[arr objectAtIndex:0]];
   NSString *url = [myUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```